# How to return response body from function with retrofit and kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

Here is my code:

```
fun getRandomComputerDetails(context: Context) {
    if (isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
        val retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BuildConfig.API_BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()

        val service: RandomComputerApiService =
            retrofit.create(RandomComputerApiService::class.java)

        val listCall: Call<RandomComputerApiResponse> = service.getRandomComputer()

        listCall.enqueue(object : Callback<RandomComputerApiResponse> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<RandomComputerApiResponse>,
                response: Response<RandomComputerApiResponse>
            ) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val randomComputerList: RandomComputerApiResponse? = response.body()
                    if (randomComputerList != null) {
                        // TODO how to return randomComputerList?
                    }
                    Log.i("Response result", "$randomComputerList")
                } else {
                    when (response.code()) {
                        400 -> {
                            errorDialogHandler(context, R.string.dialog_error_400)
                            Log.e("Error 400", "Bad Connection")
                        }
                        404 -> {
                            errorDialogHandler(context, R.string.dialog_error_404)
                            Log.e("Error 404", "Not Found")
                        }
                        500 -> {
                            errorDialogHandler(context, R.string.dialog_error_500)
                            Log.e("Error 500", "Server Error")
                        }
                        else -> {
                            errorDialogHandler(context, R.string.dialog_error_generic_error)
                            Log.e("Error", "Generic Error")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<RandomComputerApiResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e("Response error", t.message.toString())
            }
        })
    } else {
        // NO INTERNET CONNECTION
        errorDialogHandler(context, R.string.dialog_error_no_internet_connection)
    }
}
```

How can i return my `randomComputerList` body in order to use it in a Fragment? I'm using retrofit2 and my idea it was to separate in a specific file the function that takes care of executing the logic for the API call, and then calling it later in a fragment.

Comment: where exactly have you written this code? in fragment, viewmodel?

Comment: a simple kotlin file, in a separate folder. Am I doing it wrong? I'm still not experienced with retrofit, but I wanted to simplify the code and didn't want to put everything in one file. So I don't know how to get the response body back from the function

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create interface and return result through it for example I have created a ResultListener interface

```
interface ResultListener<S> {
    fun onSuccess(successModel: S)
    fun onFail(any: String?)
    fun onError(e: Throwable?)
}
```

and pass interface and take result from interface using `resultListener.onSuccess(randomComputerList)` on `response.isSuccessful`

```
fun getRandomComputerDetails(context: Context, resultListener: ResultListener<RandomComputerApiResponse>) {
    if (isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
        val retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BuildConfig.API_BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()

        val service: RandomComputerApiService =
            retrofit.create(RandomComputerApiService::class.java)

        val listCall: Call<RandomComputerApiResponse> = service.getRandomComputer()

        listCall.enqueue(object : Callback<RandomComputerApiResponse> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<RandomComputerApiResponse>,
                response: Response<RandomComputerApiResponse>
            ) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val randomComputerList: RandomComputerApiResponse? = response.body()
                    if (randomComputerList != null) {
                        // TODO how to return randomComputerList?
                        resultListener.onSuccess(randomComputerList)
                    }
                    Log.i("Response result", "$randomComputerList")
                } else {
                    when (response.code()) {
                        400 -> {
                            errorDialogHandler(context, R.string.dialog_error_400)
                            Log.e("Error 400", "Bad Connection")
                        }
                        404 -> {
                            errorDialogHandler(context, R.string.dialog_error_404)
                            Log.e("Error 404", "Not Found")
                        }
                        500 -> {
                            errorDialogHandler(context, R.string.dialog_error_500)
                            Log.e("Error 500", "Server Error")
                        }
                        else -> {
                            errorDialogHandler(context, R.string.dialog_error_generic_error)
                            Log.e("Error", "Generic Error")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<RandomComputerApiResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e("Response error", t.message.toString())
            }
        })
    } else {
        // NO INTERNET CONNECTION
        errorDialogHandler(context, R.string.dialog_error_no_internet_connection)
    }
}
```

For calling this fun

```
getRandomComputerDetails(
    context = this,
    resultListener = object : ResultListener<RandomComputerApiResponse> {
        override fun onSuccess(successModel: RandomComputerApiResponse) {
            //handle success result
        }

        override fun onFail(any: String?) {
            //handle Fail result
        }

        override fun onError(e: Throwable?) {
            //handle Error
        }
    })
```

Comment: It would be better to give the ResultListener a generic return type so the returned value doesn't have to be cast to the correct type.

Comment: Answer is updated now you can pass `successModel` whichever you want in `onSuccess`

Comment: Can you give me an example please, on how can i use and call the interface Result Listener inside a fragment? I'm not familiar with interfaces

Comment: @Munir I think you need to study more basics before proceeding. Interfaces are a far more fundamental concept than making network calls.

Comment: @Munir Added how to call fun.

Comment: But yes you need to make some study on basics as @Tenfour04 suggest.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to callback interfaces is to use coroutines. To do that, mark this as a suspend function and use `await()` instead of `enqueue()`. The `await()` call must be wrapped in a try/catch to capture the failure condition (analogous to `onFailure` in `enqueue()`). And I moved the no-network condition to the start so you don't have to nest all your code in an if-block.

```
suspend fun getRandomComputerDetails(context: Context): RandomComputerApiResponse? {
    if (!isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
        // NO INTERNET CONNECTION
        errorDialogHandler(context, R.string.dialog_error_no_internet_connection)
        return null
    }
    val retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BuildConfig.API_BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()

    val service: RandomComputerApiService =
        retrofit.create(RandomComputerApiService::class.java)

    val response = try { 
        service.getRandomComputer().await() 
    } catch (t: Throwable) {
        // code for failure condition
        // errorDialogHandler(context, R.string.???)
        Log.e("Response error", t.message.toString())
        return null
    }

    if (response.isSuccessful) {
        return response.body()
    }

    when (response.code()) {
        400 -> {
            errorDialogHandler(context, R.string.dialog_error_400)
            Log.e("Error 400", "Bad Connection")
        }
        404 -> {
            errorDialogHandler(context, R.string.dialog_error_404)
            Log.e("Error 404", "Not Found")
        }
        500 -> {
            errorDialogHandler(context, R.string.dialog_error_500)
            Log.e("Error 500", "Server Error")
        }
        else -> {
            errorDialogHandler(context, R.string.dialog_error_generic_error)
            Log.e("Error", "Generic Error")
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

And then in your fragment:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    val response = getRandomComputerDetails(requireContext())
    if (response != null) {
        // Do something with response of type RandomComputerApiResponse
    }
}
```

Comment: definitely a more up to date approach because it also gets rid of `Call` and the `.enqueue` approach